# How to include a built-in Java EE library

Tags: jakarta-ee

In my Java EE app, I have the following line of code:

`import javax.persistence.CascadeType;`

When I Google `javax.persistance`, `Java EE's` website lists this as one of libraries that is built into the framework. I'm not sure though of the easiest way of finding the library for this. Initially I pressed ctrl shift O in Eclipse to include it but Eclipse removed it. Even though my code doesn't use it in my java file, it is used in an external file that my java file needs, so I need to include it.

I'm aware that if my project were using Maven, it would automatically download dependencies but this is library is part of Java EE, so there should not be any need to download anything since I already have Java EE installed.

I created a libs directory but I'm not sure how to go about finding the actual library and including it.

Comment: This [jar](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/p/Downloadpersistencejar.htm) has the class you are looking for. FYI, ctrl+shift+O in eclipse removes unused imports.

Comment: The link you gave doesn't work.

Comment: Isn't this package automatically installed when you install Java EE?

Comment: This jar doesn't seem to be part of the standard Java library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can download JavaEE SDK and install it on your system: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/downloads
2. Then you set class path reference to your class/project.
3. In Eclipse, goto Help--> Eclipse Marketplace.. then search for Java EE, select appropriate plugin to install.

Comment: I do have JEE SDK installed. Can you explain in more detail how you "set class path reference to your class/project" - Thanks!